# MYSQL - test VARCHAR for ZERO Equivilants

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that gets populated from a flat file with 20 million rows a daily. I have one field 'app_value' that is a varchar(24) that is a mix of text and numbers.  I want to run a batch task every day to normalize all the values that are equivalent of zeros.  Checking the database I have seen at least the following zero equivalent values but I think there are others.

```
0
0.0
0.000000
```

My plan was to cast to decimal and check if that that cast was equal to 0.  If so I will update the value to '0'.  To test my theory I ran

```
SELECT d.id, d.pp_value, CAST('d.app_value' as DECIMAL(20,6))
```

It seemed to work okay on the zero equivalent numbers however I was not that surprised to see that when 'app_value' is a character it is also cast to 0.000000.  Is there  a better way to do this?  I need to protect against null, blanks and characters.   I also need to be concerned about efficiency as I have to do this against 20 million rows every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match against a [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html):

```
WHERE d.app_value RLIKE '^0+(\\.0*)?$'
```

Of course, this would not be particularly efficient (as it will require a full table scan on every invocation: indexes are of no help).  If at all possible, I'd suggest checking for zeroes when loading data into the table (either directly within `LOAD DATA` itself, or using triggers, or else through some external preprocessing).

Answer (score 0):

Second way to do it is with an NOT IN subquery.

This may scale better vs the regex engine on the larger datasets.. Regex engine startup/matching is relatively costly for the CPU compared to normal string matching..

**note this one is bit hacky because we "trust" on MySQL auto cast conversion**

```
select 
 *
from 
 data 
where
 number not in (

  select 
   number
  from 
   data 
  where
   number >= 'a'

) and number = 0
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7118e7/2